# Find $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\frac{3x}{x+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a problem in solving this assignment question,pls help

> Evaluate the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1 \to \infty}$ , if it exists:
>
> $a_n = e^{\frac{3n}{n+1}}$
>
> $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{3n}{n+1}}$

Comment: Hint: look at your [last-posed question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2189582/43239).

Comment: You need to post your work with the question on this site.

Answer (score 2):

it is $$e^{\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}=e^3$$

Answer (score 2):

> **Theorem:** Let $f$ be a continuous function at $c$. Then for every function $g$, $$\lim_{x\to c} f(g(x))=f\left(\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\right)$$ furthermore, if $f$ is continuous at $x$ for all $x>k$ for some $k$ then $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(g(x))=f\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\right)$$

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}(3x)/(x+1)=3$, by this theorem the answer is $e^3$

Answer (score 0):

The exponential is continous and clearly $\frac{3n}{n+1}$ goes to $3$ as $n\to\infty$.

Thus $\lim_n \exp{\frac{3n}{n+1}}=e^3$.

Comment: @IsiraMW: you're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\frac{3x}{x+1}}
=\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{3\frac{x}{x+1}}
= e^{3\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x+1}}
= e^{3\cdot 1}
= e^3$$